# How to create a web service for MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I have an application that is built on MarkLogic server (using XQuery). Now I want to create a mobile version of this application from Java interface sending JSON as input and output, I am totally unaware with MarkLogic REST libraries how they work, although I have read then but didn't find any exact answer from where I had to start, please let know how to start with this kind of application.

Answer (score 1):

For MarkLogic 6, start here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAmPKYgJaN and then see http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/rest

For MarkLogic 5 see community sponsored api at http://github.com/marklogic/Corona and https://github.com/marklogic/Corona/wiki

Comment: Norm Walsh wrote another REST library that's very easy to use: https://github.com/marklogic/ml-rest-lib

Comment: Yep.  Norm's library is for building your own REST endpoints - mostly for mapping URLs to your XQY code.  The MarkLogic REST API and Corona are sets of REST endpoints you can use out-of-the-box (they are both built on top of Norm's library fyi).

Answer (score 0):

For MarkLogic 6+, you can use the [MarkLogic Java Client API](http://developer.marklogic.com/products/java). There is a guide for [building Java-based MarkLogic applications](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [XQRS](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs), it works like JAX-RS but it's for XQuery. Create beautiful RESTful Services for MarkLogic with ease.